# converting text file annotation to xml files

Tags: python, xml, deep-learning

I have generated around 7000 images and ground truths for scene text detection.I want to train this on text boxes.The model wants the annotation format to be in xml format,to be specific,this is how it looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<annotation>
    <object>
        <difficult>1</difficult>
        <content>###</content>
        <name>text</name>
        <bndbox>
            <x1>261</x1>
            <y1>138</y1>
            <x2>284</x2>
            <y2>140</y2>
            <x3>279</x3>
            <y3>158</y3>
            <x4>260</x4>
            <y4>158</y4>
            <xmin>260</xmin>
            <ymin>138</ymin>
            <xmax>284</xmax>
            <ymax>158</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <content>HarbourFront</content>
        <name>text</name>
        <bndbox>
            <x1>288</x1>
            <y1>138</y1>
            <x2>417</x2>
            <y2>140</y2>
            <x3>416</x3>
            <y3>161</y3>
            <x4>290</x4>
            <y4>157</y4>
            <xmin>288</xmin>
            <ymin>138</ymin>
            <xmax>417</xmax>
            <ymax>161</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <content>CC22</content>
        <name>text</name>
<bndbox>
```

i have around 7000 text,one for each image,a sample text file contents look like this

`﻿135,34,210,34,210,57,135,57,Tobii
224,34,321,34,321,57,224,57,TX300
335,34,388,34,388,63,335,63,Eye
400,34,517,34,517,57,400,57,Tracker
140,67,171,67,171,80,140,80,300
181,66,202,66,202,80,181,80,###
212,66,294,66,294,83,212,83,sampling
305,67,337,67,337,80,305,80,rate
140,85,171,85,171,99,140,99,and
180,85,251,85,251,99,180,99,freedom
259,85,275,85,275,99,259,99,###
282,87,373,87,373,99,282,99,movement`

is there anyway i can convert these text file contents to the xml format shown above?
any suggestions would be really helpful.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly just use a template for each xml element and paste the list of attributes into the template.

E.g.

```
xml_substring_list = []

for txt_file_name in txt_file_names:

    with open(txt_file_name, 'r') as file_in:
        obj_attributes_string = file_in.readline().strip()
        obj_attributes_split = obj_attributes_string.split(',') //list of individual attribute strings

    new_xml_substring = """    <object>
        <difficult>{}</difficult>
        <content>{}</content>
        <name>{}</name>
        <bndbox>
            <x1>{}</x1>
            <y1>{}</y1>
            <x2>{}</x2>
            <y2>{}</y2>
            <x3>{}</x3>
            <y3>{}</y3>
            <x4>{}</x4>
            <y4>{}</y4>
            <xmin>{}</xmin>
            <ymin>{}</ymin>
            <xmax>{}</xmax>
            <ymax>{}</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>""".format(*obj_attributes_split)

    xml_substring_list.append(new_xml_substring)
//Create full xml by concatenating substrings and adding wrapping xml string
```